# Does the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = (x + a_n)^2$ converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

So the questions says, let $a_n$ be a sequences of real numbers such that $\limsup |a_n| = 0$. Let $X = [0, 1]$ and for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the function  $\space$     $f_n :$

$X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$: $\space$
$f_n(x) = (x + a_n)^2$. 
Does this sequence of functions converge uniformly?

Here is my work:

So since $\limsup |a_n| = 0$ we know that $\lim a_n$ = 0. Now we have:

$|(x + a_n)^2 - x ^2 | = | (a_n)^2 + 2x a_n |$
By triangle inequality we have $| (a_n)^2 + 2x a_n | \leq |(a_n)^2| + |2xa_n|$.

Since $\lim a_n = 0$ we have $ | a_n - 0| < \epsilon^2 $ and
$|2x||a_n - 0| < 2x \epsilon$. Since $X$ is bounded above by 1, $|2x||a_n - 0| < 2 \epsilon$.
Thus, $| (a_n)^2 + 2x a_n | < 2\epsilon + \epsilon^2$. Which means these sequence of functions converges uniformly. Is my approach right?

Comment: Yes....all are correct...........

Comment: You missed the right exit: Estimate further from: $|(x+a_n)^2-x^2|=|(a_n)^2+2xa_n|\leq|(a_n)^2|+|2xa_n|\leq|(a_n)^2|+(??)2|a_n|$!

Comment: Sorry isn't (??) = x? I don't quite get what you mean that I missed the right exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your answer a bit more rigorous. Note that the $\lim\sup$ condition is equivalent to saying that $\lim a_n=0$ because $$0\le\lim\inf |a_n|\le\lim\sup|a_n|=0.$$ So for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N_\epsilon$ such that for all $n\ge N_\epsilon$ we have $|a_n|<\epsilon$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then for all $n\ge N_\epsilon$ and all $x\in[0,1]$ we have

\begin{align}
|f_n(x)-x^2|&=|a_n^2+2xa_n|\\
&\le |a_n|^2+2x|a_n|\\
&\le \epsilon^2+2\epsilon
\end{align}

as in your argument.

Consequently, for every $\delta>0$, there is an $M_\delta$ such that
for all $n\ge M_\delta$ and all $x\in[0,1]$

\begin{align}
|f_n(x)-x^2|\le \delta.
\end{align}

Indeed, we can take always find an $\epsilon_\delta>0$ such that $\epsilon_\delta^2+2\epsilon_\delta\le\delta$; for example, take $\epsilon_\delta=\delta/3$ in case $\delta\le 1$, and $\epsilon_\delta=1/3$ if $\delta>1$. Then $M_\delta:=N_{\epsilon_\delta}$ will do the trick.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found my answer useful.